# Only second ping succeeds - maybe arp?

Tags: networking, configuration, local-area-network, local

i tried to set up a local network without any routers etc. 
Components are one notebook (Win7), a compact embedded 2013 board with two lan interfaces and a pc(Win 7) with also two lan interfaces.
The purpose is debugging an application from the notebook via VS2012 on the ce board. The application includes a tcp client which tries to connect to the tcp server on the pc.
This are the ip adresses i configured for the component lan adapters:

notebook: 192.168.0.1

ce board: eth A1: 192.168.0.21
          eth B1: 192.168.0.11

pc      : eth 7: 192.168.0.12 (The second is called eth 2...)

Subnetmask is always 255.255.255.0

They are connected over lan wire like following:

notebook (192.168.0.1) -> ce board (192.168.0.21)

ce board (192.168.0.11) -> pc (192.168.0.12)

Executing "ipconfig" in the command line shows me that this part works as expected. 
Now i try to ping to check if they can reach eachother. The notebook and the ce board can ping eachother without problems. Ping from pc to ce board also works fine. But if i try to ping from ce board to the pc (ping 192.168.0.12), always the first fails...Results is(in shortform since i cannot take a screenshot):

Error 11010

Error 11010

Error 11010

Error 11003

Error code 11010 means: WSA_QOS_ADMISSION_FAILURE (0x2B02) Error due to lack of resources.

Error code 11003 means: WSANO_RECOVERY (0x2AFB) A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.

If i execute the ping again, it is working fine. Problem is my application(VS2012) is not able to connect to the tcp server.
If i wait a while and execute the ping again, the first one fails again...

I also switch the two lan wires connected to the ce board, like following:

notebook (192.168.0.1) -> ce board (192.168.0.11)

ce board (192.168.0.21) -> pc (192.168.0.12)

Now the ping from ce board to the notebook shows the strange behaviour...And i cannot debugg over lan with VS2012..So its only the second LAN adapter(ethB1) causing the problem.

I've read that it might be a problem with arp? Can this be? And if yes how can i fix it?
In the post i've read it was recommended to use "arp -a" to get more information. As far as i know arp.exe does not exist on the ce device...

I am happy for any information!
Thank you for reading!

And to the downvoter. It would be nice to tell me what you do not like, so maybe i can change it or in worst case delete the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two networks there, with the CE board connected to both. The problem might be that those two networks seem to be sharing a single IP space (you don't mention the subnet masks on the interfaces in question). If you have one device connected to two different networks that are sharing the same IP space, you might have problems. Try changing the third octet of the IP addresses of both the PC and the CE board interface connected to the PC.